# Debugging RSpec patch on user info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this RSpec:

```
describe "submitting to the update action" do
  before { patch user_path(user) }
  specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
end
```

It's erroring out. How do I debug this? I would like to see what the actual response is.

Comment: `tail -f log/test.log`

Comment: Can you share the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: i think you should read this: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: @phoet I have read that. Thanks. I would suggest breaking each subject into a separate blog post.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Updated in my answer.

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin I had hundreds of tests. I was getting lost in the test log. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was running `bundle exec rspec spec/`
The error message was not specific enough:

```
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:65 # Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action
```

When I ran `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb`

I got a more detailed error message:

```
  1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/>.
       Expected "http://www.example.com/signin" to be === "http://www.example.com/".
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:65:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Solution: `expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)`